# How to create jQuery plugin with method for <input type="file"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have begun to learn JavaScript/jQuery yesterday. So my question seems primitively maybe.

**Part One - completed**

I created HTML code which you cas see below. Its just for choosing some files and show their names + there is button which seems like image here. Image instead of typical `<input type="file"...` Therefore its hiden - display is set to "none":

```
.img > input
{
  display: none;
}
```

but I just put comment here for the snippet to right work on web here. You can try it - it works right as I want. Just without images/icons here on web.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  
  <style>
    .img > input
    {
      //display: none;
    }
    
    .center 
    {
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>
  
  <script>
    friendlyInputFile = function() 
    {
      var input = document.getElementById('file');
      var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
      output.innerHTML += '<img src=\'Images/icon.jpg\'align="middle">';
      for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i)   
        {output.innerHTML += ' ' + input.files.item(i).name + '<br>';}
    }
  </script>
  
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
  <div class="img">
  
    <label for="file">
        <img src="Images/chooseImage.jpg"/>
    </label>
    
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple onchange="javascript:friendlyInputFile()"/>  
    
    <br><br>Choosen images:
    
    <div class="center" id="fileList"></div>
    
  </div>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

**Part Two - not completed**

Now I am struggling with put this `<script>` and `<styles>` into some jQuery plugin...
My task is to make code something like:

```html
<html>
<body>
 <input type=“file“ id=“inputFile“>
 <script type=“text/javascript“>
  $(function() {
   $(“#inputFile“).friendlyInputFile();
});
 <script>
```

I try at least put `<script>` alone into my jQuery but I am probably not able to do it right.

So i have my HTML with `<script>` and function `friendlyInputFile()` within. You can see below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.friendlyInputFile.js"></script>
    
  <style>
    .img > input
    {
      //display: none;
    }
    
    .center 
    {
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>
  
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
  <div class="img">
  
    <label for="inputFile">
        <img src="Images/chooseImage.jpg"/>
    </label>     
    
    <input type="file" id="inputFile"/>  
    
  <script type=“text/javascript“>   
      $(function(){  
        $("#inputFile").friendlyInputFile();  
      });
  </script>

    <br><br>Choosen files:
    
    <div class="center" id="fileList"></div>
    
  </div>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

And my jQuery file is here:

```js
// JavaScript Document
(function($)  {
    $.fn.friendlyInputFile = function(){
                      
         $(this).ready(function(){
           var input = document.getElementById('file');
           var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
           output.innerHTML += '<img src=\'Images/icon.jpg\'align="middle">';
           for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i)   
             {output.innerHTML += ' ' + input.files.item(i).name + '<br>';}
             
         });  
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Of coarse it doesnt work...
Please rescue me somebody. Whats wrong with my HTML file/jQuery file?

Comment: I found a typo.  Change your selector to #inputFile ???

<script type=“text/javascript“>   
      $(function(){  
        $("inputFile").friendlyInputFile();  
      });
  </script>

Comment: nice work mate, nice first question! cannot help now!

Comment: It doesnt work... :/ 

And I realised now that i must create friendlyInputFile() method which include almost whole code for this. More precisely, this method should transform "input file" to image as well as in my first successful part. So I think that method must include script, css and maybe images...

Answer (score 0):

**I get back to my work almost after one year and I figured it out finally!**
**So here is Part Two - finally completed.**

I cleaned my HTML file and delete some redundant code. Here is HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="friendlyInputFile.jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="inputFile" />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#inputFile").friendlyInputFile();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It has much more less code. Just two lines for jQuery library and my jQuery plugin. In body there is input for files and than one function applicated on this input. This function is in my jQuery plugin. This is inside my jQuery plugin:

```js
jQuery.fn.friendlyInputFile = function () {

    // create label and append image to this label
    var label = $("<label>").append('<img src=\'Images/buttonImage.jpg\'align="middle">');
    var input = this; // in this case 'this' is '<input type="file" id="inputFile" />'

    input.appendTo(label); // image label append to input
    $('body').append(label); // write this label on page in body section
    input.hide(); // hide input (image is still visible)

    $("body").append("<br><br><br>Choosen files:<br>"); // just another text on page in body section

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#inputFile").on("change", function () {

            var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
            $("body").append("<br> &emsp;&emsp;" + '<img src=\'Images/icon.jpg\'align="middle">' + "  " + filename);

        })
    });
}
```

I putted lot of comment here so I think its clear. In main function its just taking name of file and than It write this name next to little icon. It seems like that:

[image: "Vybrat soubory" is buttonImage. It means "choose files".]

"Vybrat soubory" is buttonImage. It means "choose files".